# Return not working

Tags: java, android

```
private String getDefaultValue() {
    boolean hasSetDefaultValues                 = setDefaultValues();
    //String theDefaultValue                      = null;

    if (hasSetDefaultValues) {
        String defaultValue                     = myHelper.getDefaultValue();
        boolean isNotNull                       = defaultValue != null;
        boolean hasLength                       = false;
        if (isNotNull) {
            hasLength                           = defaultValue.length() > 0;
        }

        boolean isValidServer                   = isNotNull && hasLength;
        if (isValidServer) {
            Log.d("skt", "inside" + defaultValue);//<-- This gets printed
            //theDefaultValue                     = defaultValue;
            return defaultValue;//Comment this when uncommenting line above
        }
    }

    //return theDefaultValue;
    return null;//Comment this when uncommenting line above
}
```

I have debugged the code. The log statement gets printed in the if statement. But the `return` statement below it does not execute instead it goes to the outermost `return` and returns `null`.

If I uncomment the commented code then I will get the proper value, but still the outermost `return` get to be working.

I am using Java 1.8.0_111

Android 5.1

Android studio version 1.5

TLDR; inner `return` not working

Comment: already tried to rebuild and redeploy your code?

Comment: i highly doubt the `return` doesn´t work. There has to be something different happens, which isn´t recreatable with the given code.

Comment: Are you sure '`defaultValue`' is NOT NULL ? What is the value it holds ?

Comment: Since commenting _return_  in the _if clause_ is working, therefore I think you should remove return keyword from it (Although not a good practice as all code paths should return some value), also try updating Android Studio, you are using quite an older version of it.

Comment: @javaguy I am checking for NULL and assigning the result in a boolean. Only if it s not NULL log will be printed. 
Everytime log will get printed, but the return won't be working.

Comment: @KevinEsche The line just above return works (The log statement). I debugged it by putting break point. I can see the defaultValue variable holds the value in my debug window. But the return is not happening.

Comment: Is the application multi threaded?

Comment: Yes. But all the methods I called in this function runs in the same thread. I checked it.

Comment: OK. That is still where I'd put some more debugging time into. Returns simply don't 'don't work'. My guess is that defaultValue is not null, and the method returns defaultValue correctly. defaultValue is then nulled by some other thread.

Comment: @reden I put break point in the code and debugged. I can see the code traveling upto log statement. It gets printed and suddenly the next execution is last return statement. The inner doesn't even get triggered.. I don't understand the default value being modified by some other thread. Because the scope of variable is only inside the if block...

Comment: And if you put a log message just before the final 'return', does it get triggered? I meant that the returned value can be modified by other threads when it has been retrieved from this method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128697/discussion-between-skt-and-reden).

Comment: If you're just basing your analysis on where the current line indicator goes in the debugger, I've found sometimes when moving between blocks like an inner return or try-catch it incorrectly indicates which line is being executed.  I would rely more on logging to determine something like this.  And as has been said before, there is effectively no chance that you have discovered a bug causing a return statement to not exit the method.  Something else is going on.